# How can I generate polygons like in a Voronoi diagram/Thiessen Polygons and get the nodes for each of the polygons?

Tags: java, algorithm, gis, polygon, voronoi

I want to be able to generate a set of polygons where I can extract all nodes for every polygon. For example:

```
Polygon 1 - (0, 0),(0,2),(2,0)
Polygon 2 - (0, 2),(2,2),(2,0)
Polygon 3 - (0, 2),(5,5),(8,5),(8,0),(2,0)
And so on...
```

[image]

I'm not interested in available tools since this is just a part of a project. I want to be able to insert random points to generate this random dataset with polygons and its nodes coordinates.

Where do I start? Is there an algorithm I can implement in a programming language? BTW: the data is supposed to be used in a PostgreSQL database as geometries. The language I want to use is Java.

Comment: The Wikipedia article [Voronoi diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) gives the math behind creating a diagram.  You can create a Swing GUI and draw images.  The Oracle tutorial [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) will take you through the steps.  Skip the Netbeans section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Tinfour project has a Java class called the BoundedVoronoiDiagram that may be useful to you as a source of ideas, see [Tinfour.org](https://github.com/gwlucastrig/Tinfour).   There an example application called ExampleVoronoi that I used (slightly modified) to produce the following picture from 10 vertices:
[image]

Adding the following code to the end of the demo produces a list of polygons and their vertices. The code identifies polygons as either open (unbounded) or closed (bounded and finite):

```
List<ThiessenPolygon> polygons = diagram.getPolygons();
for (ThiessenPolygon p : polygons) {
    Vertex v = p.getVertex(); // defining vertex for polygon
    String openString = p.isOpen() ? "open  " : "closed";
    double area = p.getArea();
    System.out.format("Vertex %2d, polygon is %s, area=%5.2f%n",
            v.getIndex(), openString, area);
    List<IQuadEdge> edges = p.getEdges();
    for (IQuadEdge e : edges) {
        Vertex a = e.getA(); // first point in edge
        System.out.format("   %12.6f, %12.6f%n", a.getX(), a.getY());
    }
}
```

For example:

```
Vertex  9, polygon is closed, area= 0.09
       0.358217,     0.496937
       0.625090,     0.764692
       0.454992,     0.887576
       0.181977,     0.854051
```